# Implementing Listener into a java - Kotlin plugin

Tags: kotlin, spigot

Im trying to create a Minecraft Plugin using Kotlin, I converted the project to kotlin and did all the necessary stuff, I created an event listener but havent figured how to implement the Listener interface.

```
import org.bukkit.Material
import org.bukkit.entity.Creeper
import org.bukkit.entity.Skeleton
import org.bukkit.entity.Zombie
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntitySpawnEvent
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack
import java.net.http.WebSocket.Listener

class MobSpawnEvent : Listener {


}
```

that's what I tried but it doesnt seem to work as my Main.class file says "Make MobSpawnEvent implement org.bukkit.listener"

I tried using the " : " operator but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the good class. `java.net.http.WebSocket.Listener` isn't from spigot, you should replace it by `org.bukkit.listener`.